# Sum of array values at dictionary positions only - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, for-loop, sum

I have x amounts of data sets to post into a line graph, and I want an additional line produced that is the sum of all dictionary entries at specific positions (in this instance, it's a date of entry). I only have 1 dictionary since the data is pulled prior from a database - dictionary called `all_users_experiences".

I'm trying to add the values together at each dictionary position and push into another array so i can then divide each position by the number of users to get the sum of each position, but for the life of me I can only find examples of regular arrays having positions appended, not dictionary values. New to JavaScript so any help would be wonderful!

arrays:
(2) [Array(30), Array(30)]

array contents (each number having a key is causing me the issue!):

(30) [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 7]

(30) [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6]

I've successfully made this work with regular lists of number, but not dictionary values!

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT:
Orignal unaltered Data was parsed into JS via python JSON can only show the pulled data from this file for sensitivity reasons. numbers in original question content is what is being collated with below.

[image: Snapshot of HTML console:]

Prior code tried (1 attempt of many...):

```js
  console.log(all_users_experiences) //Producing 2 arrays
  console.log(all_users_experiences[0])
  console.log(all_users_experiences[1])

  var total_users = Object.keys(linegraph_data).length;

  user_exp_aggregate = []

  for (var i = 0; i < total_users.length; i++){
    user_exp_aggregate.push(all_users_experiences[i][0] + all_users_experiences[i][1]);
    console.log(user_exp_aggregate)
  }
  console.log("Total list: " + user_exp_aggregate)
```

EDIT2

Amended as per suggestion by Bergi but no data is being added to new array still :

```js
  user_exp_aggregate = []
  console.log("Initial list: "+ user_exp_aggregate)
  for (var i = 0; i < total_users.length; i++){
    user_exp_aggregate.push(all_users_experiences[0][i] + all_users_experiences[1][i]);
    console.log("updated list: " + user_exp_aggregate)
  }
  console.log("Total list: " + user_exp_aggregate)
```

[Amended snapshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg48o.png)

example of how current data from arrays is being used in graph (trying to create a 3rd line graph data set showing the average between all users!):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcHXq.png)

Comment: please add your code and the arrays in literal notation.

Comment: There is no dictionary as such in javascript and so, you didn't get anything. Can you post a sample of input and output as well as what you have done till now? This will make other contributors to understand your problem and help you out easily

Comment: This doesn't look like a "dictionary", it's just an array.

Comment: You're looking for `user_exp_aggregate.push(all_users_experiences[0][i] + all_users_experiences[1][i])` - notice the indices

Comment: Hi does anyone have any thoughts that could help? Been racking my brains on this one for days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```js
all_users_experiences = [
  [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7, 7],
  [5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6]
]

user_exp_aggregate = []

//Loop to the full length for each
for (var i = 0; i < all_users_experiences[0].length; i++) {
  user_exp_aggregate.push(all_users_experiences[0][i] + all_users_experiences[1][i]);
}

console.log("Total list: " + user_exp_aggregate)

//If you want to divide each value by total user count
user_exp_average = []

//var total_users = Object.keys(linegraph_data).length;
var total_users = 2 //Assuming total users are 2
for (var i = 0; i < user_exp_aggregate.length; i++) {
  user_exp_average.push(user_exp_aggregate[i] / total_users);
}

console.log("Average: " + user_exp_average)
```

The issue happening in edit 2 part of code it that, the loop is only running till total user length. But as per your specification, you need to loop through all experiences to get the aggregate array and then divide each value by total number of users to get the average.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.